# Historicity of which Biblical characters is recognized by Archaeology/History?

Tags: history

I know that Historicity of certain Old testament Kings is recognized.

However some like Jonah or Job aren't know to fields of Archaeology or History.

What information, evidence do we have and for what figures? (The list can include both known and unknown or debated figures)

Comment: Job is hard to place (for one) since there are two versions of his story and it is the oldest book in the scriptures. To understand what that means, it means that Job was in antiquity when Moses was leaving Egypt.

Comment: @RiverC: besides the book of Job, what other version is there?

Comment: The Greek Septuagint is significantly different than the Hebrew Masoretic.

Comment: @MonikaMichael Here are 2 quotes 

"It was alleged that the ancient city of Nineveh did not exist, therefore Textual Critic alleged that the Bible had to be false. Then Nineveh was discovered."

"It was alleged once again by Textual Critics that the historic empire of the Hittites had never existed. Then the Hittite inscriptions were found, and then the Hittite empire and those archives were found."

Rather than try to authenticate the Bible with archeology, which often seems to be catching up, it might be better to look to the Bible as the authenticating source.

Comment: This is too broad. The fact that you're asking for a list shows that. Narrow it down to a few certain characters, like Abraham, Sarah, and Lot, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

There are tons of resources. I've never seen an itemized list, but I've seen dozens of resources like [this one](http://www.irr.org/mit/bible-archaeology.html).

Of course, you'll find that some findings are disputed, and as is the case with any science, new discoveries often change existing assumptions, so such a list would be ever-changing.

There is  [list of 61 such people here](http://www.aish.com/ci/sam/48969466.html).

More at [this set of search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Biblical%20people%20verified%20by%20archaeology&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=VNz&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=list%20of%20Biblical%20people%20verified%20by%20archaeology&oq=list%20of%20Biblical%20people%20verified%20by%20archaeology&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...86727.90346.1.91266.8.8.0.0.0.0.152.1149.0j8.8.0...0.0.vY5vquGzDas&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f16fd9087f0f178c&biw=1280&bih=619).

Answer (score 0):

According to the so called "low chronology" described by Professor Israel Finkelstein of Tel Aviv University, the six-chambered gates, palaces, and stabes at Megiddo previously ascribed to Solomon by Yadin and Dever were actually built about a hundred years later by Omri and Ahab, kings of the northern kingdom of Israel. David and Solomon are likely to be actual historical kings of the southern kingdom of Judah, but they were little more than rulers of a poor and sparsley populated highland chiefdom and not the powerful kings of a grand united monarchy of Israel and Judah combined into a singe nation as described in the Bible because no such thing existed at the time. For more information please read the book called "The Forgotten Kingdom" by Israel Finkelstein or simply google "low chronology"or "Israel Finkelstein" or search for these phrases in Youtube for his really excellent and often humorous lectures on this subject. Incidentally, low chronology is supported by radiocarbon dating of the relevant strata of archaeological excavations in the holy lands. In an article I wrote I showed that these radiocarbon dates are sufficiently precise to differentiate between the time of Solomon and that of the rise of the Omride Dynasty in the north. My article may be found here.

http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2572966

The Forgotten Kingdom is available at amazon.com of course but I believe it is also available as a pdf file online. Please try this link. It should work.

https://www.academia.edu/4763350/The_Forgotten_Kingdom_The_Archaeology_and_History_of_Northern_Israel

Comment: Please [edit] this to add capital letters and punctuation.